# Can I add autorefresh to SSRS report only when parameters change?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, refresh, reporting

[image: Imagen]

I have this report in SSRS, how can I Add autorefresh by code only when parameters change by User (Without clicking red button)

Comment: When you press that refresh button after updating the parameter, the report is still going to use the original parameters.

Answer (score 1):

### YOU CAN'T

have the report automatically update after the user changes a parameter. There's no functionality built in for the parameters.

### BUT YOU CAN

create your own parameter selection inside the report body that the user can click on and will rerun the report.

For this report, the Rate parameter would be hidden.

A table with one column is added to the report with the Rate parameter data as the table's source and the Rates as the detail value.

An ACTION is added to call the same report and populate the Rate parameter with the Rate field from the new Rate table.

When a user clicks on a row in the new parameter table, the report action will rerun the report using the click-on value for the Rate.

[image]

Comment: This doesnt work. Its the same that click View Report or Refresh button. Thanks

Comment: @Javi - not sure what you mean. When you click on a Rate in the new Rate parameter table, the Action should rerun the report with the selected rate for the rate parameter. The user shouldn't need to click on a button. Are you seeing different results?